# Slow select on Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with a client's database who's schema cannot be changed and I'm getting plagued with my query that is extremely slow.  I'm looking for any tips or tricks that might help me speed up this query even in the slightest.

My query looks like the following

```
select sb.account_id AS account id,
s.work AS work,
s.type AS type,
s.counter AS counter,
a.name AS content_name,
a.content_type AS content_type,
a.created_at::date AS created_date,
st.name AS strategy_name,
t.name AS content_author,
p.name AS content_group
from
table1 sb,
table2 s,
table3 a,
table4 st,
table5 t,
table6 s,
table7 p
where
sb.account_id = 1234
and s.account_id = sb.account_id
and a.account_id = sb.account_id
and st.account_id = sb.account_id
and t.account_id = sb.account_id
and p.account_id = sb.account_id
```

Does anyone out there have any ideas on how I can speed up this queries execution time?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: table2 and table6 use the same alias, this example could never work. For clarity I would recommend to use JOIN when you have to join tables.